# systemd: restart service when it hits a file descriptor limit

Tags: linux, systemd

I have a service which is leaking file descriptors. It is managed via systemd. Is there a way I can restart that service when it hits a particular numbers of file descriptors. Any pointers will be really helpful.

Comment: You can count them using `ls /proc/$PID/fd/ | wc -l` and reset based on the count, I suppose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by Lenniey (i was writing the script). You can create another `systemd` service and timer to make checks.

Your script may look something like

```
#!/bin/bash

SERVICE="sshd.service"
LIMIT=9

PID=$(systemctl show ${SERVICE} | grep ExecMainPID|cut -d '=' -f2)
NBFD=$(ls -l /proc/${PID}/fd | wc -l)

if [[ ( $NBFD > $LIMIT )  ]] ; then
    echo "restarting the service: ${NBFD} > ${LIMIT}"
    systemctl restart ${SERVICE}
else
    echo "service fd limit ok: ${NBFD} < ${LIMIT}"
fi
```

Then create a `service` running the script and `timer` running the service every `X` minutes